# Logarithmic Amplifier

Tags: power-electronics, instrumentation-amplifier

Which part of the circuit acts as a constant current source in logarithmic amplifier using transistors ?
[image: Logarithmic amplifier]

Comment: Where would a constant current be of advantage (outside the OpAmps)?

Comment: Perhaps this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/lm394-is-obsolete-what-is-the-new-standard-log-amp-circuit